# PlayFramework 2.2 scala close WebSocket connection

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, playframework-2.2

How can I close a WebSocket connection? The example on the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaWebSockets) works if you want to close it immediately.

But how about the following case: I want to close the connection when some condition occurs in the future. For instance, when I receive a certain message from the client.

```
def indexWS = WebSocket.using[String] {
    request => {

      var channel: Option[Concurrent.Channel[String]] = None
      var outEnumerator: Enumerator[String] = Concurrent.unicast(c => channel = Some(c))

      val myIteratee: Iteratee[String, Unit] = Iteratee.foreach[String] {gotString => {
        // received a string from the client

        if (gotString == "close_me") {
          // outEnumerator = Enumerator.eof // doesn't work
          // outEnumerator >>> Enumerator.eof // doesn't work
        }

      }}

      (myIteratee, outEnumerator)
    }
  }
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it: I had to go through the channel that I opened at

```
var outEnumerator: Enumerator[String] = Concurrent.unicast(c => channel = Some(c))
```

and the commented out block would become

```
if (gotString == "close_me") {
    channel.foreach(_.eofAndEnd())      
}
```

which will push an EOF through the enumerator and close the connection.